# Tornado WebSocket connection is not closed inside a test suite

Tags: python, unit-testing, websocket, code-coverage, tornado

I'm trying to test this WebSocket handler built with Tornado which I'm calling `main.py`

```
import tornado.websocket

class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        print(' [T] Websocket connection open')

    def on_message(self, message):
        print(' [T] Websocket message received: %s' % message)

    def on_close(self):
        print(' [T] Websocket connection closed')
```

using the builtin module `tornado.testing` with some adaptations from a simple `AsyncHTTPTestCase` example:

```
import tornado.testing
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

from main import SocketHandler

class TestWebSockets(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return tornado.web.Application([(r'/', SocketHandler)])

    @tornado.testing.gen_test
    async def test_async_client(self):

        url = "ws://localhost:" + str(self.get_http_port()) + "/"
        client = await tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(url)
        client.write_message('message')
        client.close()
```

This test passes. However, when I run `pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=.` it points out that the last line of `main.py` was not reached, i.e. the server was not closed.

Anyone knows what's happening? I already tried adding a delay after closing but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add `await tornado.gen.sleep(1)` (an async sleep which allows the other async tasks to be processed) after `client.close()` it brings coverage up to 100%.

Comment: Thanks, I was using a synchronous sleep function and that wasn't working. Do you know why?

Comment: The server-side is asynchronous python in the same process, using the same event loop. It didn't get to run at all during the synchronous sleep.

Answer (score 1):

The socket *is* closed, but you're letting the test finish without waiting for the callback to run. Whether you need to do anything about this depends on what you're doing in the close callback and whether it's necessary for the tests.

If your tests care about the callback being run, then you need to either sleep a bit to give it a chance (as you've discovered), or do something to allow the test to observe the fact that the callback is run. This is unfortunately rather clumsy; see the use of `close_future` in [Tornado's `websocket_test.py`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.4.2/tornado/test/websocket_test.py) file.